# JavaScript - jQuery.load производительность

Tags: javascript, jquery

Моя задача - подгрузка контента с другой страницы. 
Мне потребовалось добавить функцию callback. После её добавления начались проблемы с производительностью.

Вот код: `$(into).load(url + " " + from, function (){start_page();console.log('CALLBACK');});`

Вроде ничего необычного, однако, `console.log('CALLBACK');` помог мне понять, что callback вызывается странным образом. Первый раз эта функция вызывается 1 раз, второй - 2 раза, 3 - 5 раз и так всё больше и больше.

Есть какие-то предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы повторно/многократно навешиваете обработчик события, в котором вызывается код

```
$(into).load(url ...
```

так что этот код - и та функция, которая подается в `load` вторым параметром, - вызывается все большее число раз.

Comment: Гениально! Я об этом не подумал.. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @LISS На здоровье. Успехов!